# Resize images in to another directory

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

I have the following in place for all my images in `/images/500x500/`. I need to resize the images to 250x250 and have them go into the `/images/250x250/` with the **same filename**.

It doesn't create the new image in the new directory, rather it replaces the large in the same directory?

```
<?php

$files = glob("*.{png,jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($files as $file) 
{
  // get the image size
  $imagesize = getimagesize($file);
  $width_orig = $imagesize[0];
  $height_orig = $imagesize[1];

  $dst_w = 250;

  if($width_orig != $dst_w)
  {

    $dst_h_multiplier = $dst_w / $width_orig;
    $dst_h = $dst_h_multiplier * $height_orig;

    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dst_w, $dst_h ,$width_orig, $height_orig);

    imagejpeg($dst, $outputFile, 100);

$outputFile = 
    realpath(
        pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) 
        . '/../250x250/'
    ) . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

  }
}

?>
```

Comment: I think the best way to do it will be save the image with different name and than move it to the required folder and change back the original name...

Comment: @Dinesh: Dinesh, with hundreds of images this is impractical!

Comment: are you uploading 100's of images at same time?..

Comment: @Dinesh, What are you talking about?  You can easily simply output your new file to the new folder.

Comment: @Brad I was actually thinking like this.. when someone uploads a pic.. we upload it in a specific folder say 500X500 as in above case.. than once thats done another function will take that file and create a smaller version of file with diff name(store the previous name in a variable). Once this is done copy this file to another location and delete this file.. anyways I realized it not so efficient when I thought about it more...

Comment: @Dinesh: Dinesh, too much work for something that can be achieved in a simpler method :)

Comment: @Brad.. yep I realized that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$outputFile = 
    realpath(
        pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) 
        . '/../'
    ) . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

First, you need the path, which you can get with `realpath()`, along with `pathinfo()`.  Then, just append a `..` and the file name.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Also, you might not need `realpath()`.  I haven't tested.

Comment: Thanks Brad. How does that fit in with the code above that I have supplied? Unsure how it actually stores. Thank you

Comment: @Dave, You would want to use `$outputFile` when you output the image, which you do with your `imagejpeg()` line at the very end.

Comment: Thanks - going to give this a try now :)

Comment: Hey Brad, updated the question with new code and nothing happens :/

Comment: I have also set the `250x250` dir to 777 permission - still nothing

Comment: @Dave, Of course not, you're not calling `imagejpeg()`.  `imagejpeg($dst, $outputFile, 100)`  `imagejpeg()` is what does the image output.  The code I gave you is just to show one way to get the output path you want.  See the documentation here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php  Also, you might need another slash before the file name.  I'm not sure... I didn't test the code.  You can echo it out to find out.

Comment: Whoops!! Thanks, giving it another shot. Had a complete mindblank for a second!!

Comment: Updated code again. Still nothing. I echo'd out the filename and it displays, still no image creation though.

Comment: Update: It created the image but in the same directory :( overwrote the large. I'll accept your answer though as it does work :) just would love to have it creating in the other dir

Comment: @Dave, Can you post your code?  At least from what you have in your post, you aren't setting the file path until after you output the image... which won't work.

Comment: @Dave, Move this: `imagejpeg($dst, $outputFile, 100);` so that it is the last line in your `if` block, below the `$outputFile` code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19387/discussion-between-brad-and-dave)